# Execute commands on a different CLI in linux terminal from java

Tags: java, command-line-interface

I have a use case where in I have to connect to a CLI and execute commands in that CLI using java. Usually without using java, I do it by opening a linux terminal and connecting to other CLI and execute commands there. I have to implement the same using Java. I am able to run the commands on the linux terminal using Runtime.getRuntime().exec(). But, I need some help in executing the commands after connecting to a particular CLI from linux terminal using Java

Comment: *connecting to other CLI* - you mean like by using telnet or ssh?

Comment: and what is your question?

Comment: For Example(in my case its different CLI), lets take a HIVE CLI. I can access hive cli through linux terminal. I can execute commands like 'ls -l' using java on the linux terminal. But, if I want to execute "show databases" command in hive cli, I have to login to linux terminal and connect to hive cli and exexute. I want to do this Show databases command from using Java

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking how to make use of [pseudo-terminals](https://linux.die.net/man/7/pty). I was going to warn you this was likely more complicated than you were bargaining for, but a short search showed the [pty4j library](https://github.com/traff/pty4j) which may be of help.

Answer (score 0):

When you run an external program using `Runtime.exec()`, it returns a [`Process`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/) object that you can use to interact with the running process.  That object has a `getOutputStream()` method that you can use to send commands to the process, and, `getInputStream()` and `getErrorStream()` methods that you can use to read messages produced by the process.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I know this, but I am trying to find something else. Now, I got the solution to my problem. Thanks All